# Java Table class structure

Tags: java, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

First time posting, have a question about a table class I'm working on. For some reason adding a new row doesn't add the correct number of rows. I've added the code

```
public void addRow(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > rows()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    table.add(i, new ArrayList<T>());

    for(int j = 0; j < cols(); j++) {
        table.get(i).add(null);
    }
}

public void addCol(int j) {
    if (j < 0 || j > cols()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if(rows() == 0) {
        addRow(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows(); i++) {
        table.get(i).add(j, null);
    }
}
```

These here are the methods I have to add a new row and column to the table. Below is what I'm using to test. For some reason it's adding a 5th row. Not sure where from.

```
Table<Integer> table = new Table<>(Integer.class);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    table.addCol(table.cols());
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    table.addRow(table.rows());
}
```

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated, thanks!

Full Code:

```
public class Table<T> implements AbstractTable<T> {

    List<List<T>> table;

    public Table(Class<T> t) { table = new ArrayList<>(); }

    public int rows() { return table.size(); }

    public int cols() {
        if(rows() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return table.get(0).size();
        }
    }

    public T get(int i, int j) {
        if (i < 0 || i > rows() - 1 || j < 0 || j > cols()-1)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        return table.get(i).get(j);
    }

    public T set(int i, int j, T x) {
        if (i < 0 || i > rows() - 1 || j < 0 || j > cols()-1)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        return table.get(i).set(j, x);
    }

    public void addRow(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > rows()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        table.add(i, new ArrayList<T>());

        for(int j = 0; j < cols(); j++) {
            table.get(i).add(null);
        }
    }

    public void addCol(int j) {
        if (j < 0 || j > cols()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if(rows() == 0) {
            addRow(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows(); i++) {
            table.get(i).add(j, null);
        }
    }

    public void removeRow(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > rows() - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    table.remove(i);
    }

    public void removeCol(int j) {
        if (j < 0 || j > cols() - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows(); i++) {
            table.get(i).remove(j);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Table<Integer> table = new Table<>(Integer.class);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            table.addCol(table.cols());
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            table.addRow(table.rows());
        }
        System.out.println("rows: " + table.rows() + "\ncols: " + table.cols());

        table.removeCol(1);
        table.removeRow(1);

        System.out.println("rows: " + table.rows() + "\ncols: " + table.cols());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the full code of your `Table` class

Comment: Or at least a [mcve].

Comment: Did you debug your solution?

Comment: You will probably end up disliking your null values in your table. Why did you do it like that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen just using null for now while trying to figure out the issue

Comment: @Joshua posted the full code

Answer (score 0):

If you used a debugger, you’d see that you are adding the extra row in addCol

Comment: Thanks, I see that, although I have that there so that it adds a row if there are no rows already. Should it be possible to add a column to a table with no rows?

Comment: @tbarbs "Should it be possible..." this is a design question. It depends on what the specifications are. Otherwise, I believe I have answered your question... Can you check this answer as correct?

Comment: Good point, lets say that yes you need to have a row for it to be considered a table. Is there any way other than how I'm doing it to add a new column? I'm adding that row right now so that adding a column has a row it can add to if the number of rows is 0.